# HTML Table with scrollbar or select list with columns?

Tags: html

i wish to grab items from a database and put them in a fixed size 'container', which will have a scrollbar. How could i do this so that internally i can still have columns so different field lengths remain alligned within the table?

Either i need some sort of select with formatted columns or i need a table which can be a constant height and you scroll down further to see more results. At the moment ive got a table and the more results i have, the longer my actual whole page is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well you could use `{overflow-y:scroll;}` on a div for the scroll part.

Or you could use pagination in you db query, so you only have a set number of results per page if you dont like to scroll.

Comment: I need all the results to be shown at once, but i'd rather they were in a 'component' which was scrollable.

Comment: I guess im asking, can a select's option components be formatted to have columns?

Comment: No you can not use cols with a select option, the most you can do is use option groups.

Comment: Take a look at this article, http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/getting_your_di